# How to get the symlink target path in ansible

Tags: ansible

Want to check if the symlink destination is having the folder name which is passed as extra vars. The below is not working:

```yaml
- name: Print a debug message
  debug:
    msg: {{package_version}} contains ab_slink.stat.lnk_target
  register: ab_slink_exist
  when: "ab_slink.stat.lnk_target is search '{{package_version}}'"
```

getting this error:

```
\[WARNING\]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}.
```

Answer (score 2):

The contents of a `when` directive are evaluated in an implicit Jinja context -- that is, you can pretend they are already surrounded by `{{...}}` markers. You never nest `{{...}}` markers; if you want to reference a variable inside a Jinja expression, you just use the variable name. Your task should look something like this:

```yaml
- name: Print a debug message
  debug:
    msg: "{{package_version}} contains ab_slink.stat.lnk_target"
  register: ab_slink_exist
  when: "ab_slink.stat.lnk_target is search(package_version)"
```

Except this is still problematic, because you don't generally use `debug` tasks to set values. I would write something like this:

```yaml
- name: set ab_slink_exist
  set_fact:
    ab_slink_exist: "{{ ab_slink.stat.lnk_target is search(package_version) }}"
```